# What does "Order Book" mean here?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I found from a press release the following sentence:

"New deals and increased volume lead to estimated $1.3B Order Book by year end, up from $1B target"

What does this mean? Is it a firm order? My understanding is product order is not revenue yet. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, product orders are not revenue: they may include contracts that are wholly unperformed that could be terminated without penalty.

Comment: The question is about stock market order books, see tags.

Comment: @EllieKesselman No, the tag OBVIOUSLY is wrong. a $1.5 BILLION (!) order book makes ZERO sense in pretty much any stock.This is clearls an order book as in "orders for a product".

Comment: Yes, I found the following release https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20201110005750/en/Luminar-Increases-Guidance-Accelerating-Deals from Nov 10 2020, and it's product orders, not stock-related order books.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of stocks and trading, an [order book is:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_book_(trading))

> ...the list of orders (manual or electronic) that a
> stock exchange uses to record the interest of buyers and sellers in a
> particular financial instrument. A matching engine uses the book to
> determine which orders can be fully or partially executed.

An order book is organized by price level. Market depth refers to the number of shares being bid on or offered at each price point.

Order book value is the dollar value of interest on both the buy side and the sell side. It is not the dollar value of executed transactions. A $1.3B order book is an estimate of value of stocks that have not yet traded but are anticipated to be traded.